# Drag Link From Browser Address Bar To JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, address-bar

I have a Web Desktop Bookmarking site and I want users to be able to drag and drop the Site Icon from the browser bar to  my JavaScript App in another tab.  This works nicely in Chrome (if you try), but I'm not sure what the code is to accept the drop event and read the url from the link dropped in.

A quick look at my site would give an idea how this added functionality would be a useful feature. [Booky: Your Personal Bookmark Web Desktop](http://www.bookydesktop.com)

How do I do that?